# PyQGIS, Setting some types for snappingUtils

Tags: pyqgis, snapping

I have code like this:

```
self.snap_conf = QgsSnappingConfig()
...
self.snap_conf.setTypeFlag(Qgis.SnappingTypes(Qgis.SnappingType.Centroid))
self.snap_conf.setTypeFlag(Qgis.SnappingTypes(Qgis.SnappingType.Vertex))
```

It causes no error, but turns on only second type. How can I apply both (or more)?

I saw  `self.snap_conf.setType(QgsSnappingConfig.VertexAndSegment)` solution. But it doesn't work for me because I want use different types (and have option to turn them on/off while using my plugin).

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to specify multiple types using `|` notation.

```py
self.snap_conf.setTypeFlag(Qgis.SnappingTypes(Qgis.SnappingType.Vertex | Qgis.SnappingType.Vertex))
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, using

```
self.snapper = canvas.snappingUtils()
```

Instead of

```
self.snapper = QgsMapCanvasSnappingUtils(canvas)
```

And configuring the config of that snapper.

That solution uses settings of QGIS standard snapping tools and you can change settings easily.

It is not exactly what I wanted, but it works fine.